# Grails 3.0 Connecting to Database

Tags: mysql, sql, grails, build.gradle, grails-3.0

I am new to Grails 3.0, and I am having troubling connecting to MySql database. When I run the project I get several errors. I still haven't got the hang of the new .yml file.

[image: .yml file]

[image]

I modified the yml file like above. Then I changed the build.gradle file like so. (Could the java version be wrong? How do I check?)

[image]

This is the error I get then.  I have tried changing the url but nothing seems to work.

[image]

Comment: could as well be just an indenting problem around `url:` in line 124 as the error states - but since you decided, that unsearchable, uncopyable, uneditable images are the way to go, we will have a hard time reproduce your problem.

Comment: @cfrick my bad been at this a long time now ill change it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try indent-aligning 'dbCreate', and removing the space between 'url' and ':'?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps as simple as including the port on which mysql resides? This works for me.

```
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
            driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            username: root
            password: somethingsecret
            properties:
                maxActive: -1
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 1800000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 1800000
                numTestsPerEvictionRun: 3
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: true
                validationQuery: 'select 1'
```

Comment: If you use the default port (3306 in the case of MySQL/MariaDB) you can omit it since it's redundant.